# How can I get a drain cleaning bladder out of the drain?

Tags: tools, drains

My husband put a drain cleaning bladder on the hose to unclog our toilet.

[image]

Well it is now in the main drain - what's the best way to get it out?

Comment: Can you provide a better description or photo of the "cleaning bladder thing" as well as what you mean by "it is now in the main drain?"

Comment: As it isn't inflated anymore, shouldn't it be able to pass through the drain system as a solid waste?